# How to get HTML Attribute in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making customization to a cliënts WordPress website. However, I need to retrieve price information from the HTML attribute to my functions.php file. The price is being calculated and added in the attribute data-field-price="0" as you choose more products.

```
<li class="pewc-group pewc-item pewc_group_3414_3415 pewc-group-products pewc-item-products pewc-field-3415 pewc-field-count-0 pewc-item-products-checkboxes pewc-active-field" data-id="pewc_group_3414_3415" data-field-id="3415" data-field-type="products" data-field-price="0" data-field-label="" data-field-value="0"></li>
```

Since I can't use Javascript I need to get the value of data-field-price="0" ( so in this case the 0 ). How do I achieve this with only PHP? Please help.

Comment: Why can't u use javascript?

Comment: It is not a good practice to do that but what you can do is to get the entire html document content and use regular expressions to find you peice of data that you need. Use file_get_contents() function to get the html content and preg_match() to find the peice of code that you need. Again this is not a good practic - use Javascript instead.

Comment: PHP is the wrong language to use for this. PHP is a backend language that sends end-point data out to HTML, to retrieve data from HTML you should be using Javascript (JQuery) to read the DOM and to then pass the variables back to a PHP server-side processor via an AJAX request.

Comment: What if I use Javascript, how would you do it then?

Comment: @Martin I have to disagree with the statement that PHP should only be used to send out end-point data. PHP is a ["hypertext preprocessor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), and using it for HTML templating is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Is this HTML being created by your PHP engine? Or are you acting as a middleware of some kind to interpret a async request? If its from your PHP engine, then find where that attribute is being written in the first place. If its a functions.php file I would suggest some CMS (Probs Wordpress) so you could find a Hook somewhere that writes that html and capture it

Comment: Just reread and saw that it is wordpress - in that case, I'm sure you can hook into what is being written - This element is generated by WooCommerce, so there will be a hook somewhere to grab the html or even the price directly

Answer (score 2):

Add an ID to the `<li>` in the HTML file.

```
<li id="_li" class="pewc-group pewc-item pewc_group_3414_3415 pewc-group-products pewc-item-products pewc-field-3415 pewc-field-count-0 pewc-item-products-checkboxes pewc-active-field" data-id="pewc_group_3414_3415" data-field-id="3415" data-field-type="products" data-field-price="0" data-field-label="" data-field-value="0"></li>
```

Then you can use "JavaScript" in your PHP file!
Use `file_get_contents()` to read the HTML page.

```
$DOM  = new DOMDocument();
$HTML = file_get_contents("index.html");     //Read it!

@$DOM->loadHTML($HTML);                      //Load it!
$li  = $DOM->getElementById('_li');          //Get the element!
$val = $li->getAttribute('data-field-price');//Get the price!

echo $val;                                   //Write it!
```

Comment: OP stated that they can't use Javascript

Comment: @Martin they are using PHP DOM functions.

Answer (score 1):

The element is produced by WooCommerce in Wordpress. Wordpress core, and 3rd party plugins contain a huge array of filters and actions to get information like this.

WooCommerce's is documented here : [WooCommerce Hooks and Filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)

The filter in particular which may be of interest is : [woocommerce_cart_item_price](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_cart_item_price)

I am no expert of WooCommerce, but write wordpress plugins myself so I would suggest that you could get your information as follows by adding a filter into your theme (eg in your functions.php) :

```
<?php
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'theme_prefix_wc_cart_item_price', 10, 3); 
function theme_prefix_wc_cart_item_price($price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
  //See what $price and $cart_item can do for you

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spilt it as a string using the explode method or create an hidden input on your html to catch the value like that

```
<input name="data-field-price" type="hidden" value="PRICE-HERE" >
```